# Como redirecionar meu formulário para outra página?

Tags: javascript, html

Atualmente meu código está abrindo em uma nova janela a pagina de pagamento, gostaria de que ele fosse redirecionado para outra pagina quando clicasse em enviar formulário dependendo do `value` que está no `option` do segundo `dropbox`.

Tentei usar o código `window.location.href` e não funcionou.

```js
$(function() {    
  $('#btnget').click(function() {
  let formValido = document
    .getElementById("formulario")
    .checkValidity();

  if (formValido)
    window.open($('#chkveg').val());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="formulario" action="<? $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="POST">
    <select id="eassociado" name="eassociado">
        <option disabled selected value> -- Selecione uma opção -- </option>
        <option>ABRAPP</option>
        <option>ABAAI</option>
        <option>IBGC</option>
        <option>ABRACAM</option>
        <option>ABBC</option>
        <option>Associados Ancord</option>
        <option>Não Associados</option>
    </select>

    <select name="ingresso" id="chkveg">

        <option value="https://pag.ae/7ULKPL7TH">Associados Ancord + C.Dados = R$700,00</option>
        <option value="https://pag.ae/7ULKQ8Zm2">Associados Ancord Normal = R$800,00</option>
        <option value="https://pag.ae/7UTdp8_CG">Associados Entidades Apoiadoras + C.Dados = R$875,00</option>
        <option value="https://pag.ae/7UTdpwWem">Associados Entidades Apoiadoras Normal = R$1.000,00</option>
        <option value="https://pag.ae/7UTdpPZjn">Não Associados + C.Dados = R$1.100,00</option>
        <option value="https://pag.ae/7UTdq2JsG">Não Associados Normal = R$1.250,00</option>
    </select>

    <input name="envia" id="btnget" class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="INSCREVER-SE">
</form>
```

Comment: tentou o  window.location.href = "http://..." dessa forma?

Comment: sim, nao vai, ele só da como se fosse um refresh na pagina

Comment: onde está o botão que submete o formulário?

Comment: esqueci de colocar, colocando aqui

Answer (score 1):

Use `preventDefault()` para cancelar a ação do botão e altere o atributo `action` do formulário com o valor do option antes de submetê-lo manualmente:

```
$(function() {
   $('#btnget').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let formValido =  document
    .getElementById("formulario")
    .checkValidity();

      if(formValido){
         $("#formulario")
         .attr("action", $('#chkveg').val())
         .submit();
      }
   })
});
```

Comment: ainda ta abrindo numa nova aba

Comment: veja agora.....

Comment: eu coloquei href inves do action e não acontece nada, o botão não funciona. Eu tirei o preventdefault e enviou o email, mas parece que a pagina recarregou, nao trocou pra nenhuma dos links dos values nos options

Comment: parece que ele bloqueia as ações do php o preventdefault e torna o botão inutil

Comment: O preventDefault é para que o formulário não seja enviado sem validar. Testei aqui e funcionou normalmente.

Comment: quando deleto o php funciona. o php parece estar atualizando a pagina depois do envio do formulario cancelando o js

Comment: aqui eu postei o código todo junto com o php, a alteração eu só fiz no primeiro escolhida == 1 (gist.github.com/LucasMorato/6e6ac480aeebf3ba5f011e93ffadd3c7)

Answer (score 1):

Fala cara, beleza? Anexei o código no GitHub para facilitar tua vida (https://github.com/victorhermes/RedirecionarUser/blob/master/index.html). E segue o gif abaixo do código rodando. Ele redireciona conforme o valor da selection, e na mesma página. Ah, detalhe... troquei aquele seu input (que submete o formulário) por um button, conforme o código do GitHub.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código JavaScript que usei foi esse abaixo:

```
<script>      
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click', '#btnget', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        let formValido = document.getElementById("formulario").checkValidity();

        if (formValido) {
            $(location).attr('href', $('#chkveg').val())
        }

    });

});
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: esse código funcionou, se eu tiro o e.preventDefault() , mas o email nao chega, acho que ele para de executar o php com o preventdefault

Comment: Tenta colocar o button assim (<button id="btnget" class="submit-btn" type="submit">Enviar</button>). Se não der, apaga o button e tenta por o input (<input name="envia" id="btnget" class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="INSCREVER-SE">). Mas deixa o mesmo código JavaScript!

Comment: ele dá certo, só que acho que meu php atualiza a pagina e volta lá pra cima, interrompendo o javascript de direcionamento

Comment: aqui eu postei o código todo junto com o php, a alteração eu só fiz no primeiro escolhida == 1 (https://gist.github.com/LucasMorato/6e6ac480aeebf3ba5f011e93ffadd3c7)